# WordPress: Insert Custom Markup in Template

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a page.php template and I want the first section to be wrapped in `<div id="featured">` to style it differently. How do I do it?

I can't insert the div in my template since `the_content()` just outputs the whole content. I could insert the additional markup in the editor in HTML mode, but then I would have to repeat this process for every new page. Also the editor seems to insert empty `p` tags for no reason..

Markup looks like this:

```
<img>
<p>

<p>
<p>
<P>
...
```

What I want is:

```
<div id="featured">
 <img>
 <p>
</div>

<p>
<p>
...
```

What's the best way to do this?

**Edit**: Thanks for your answers. After some more searching I found exactly what I was looking for, not as straightforward as I hoped but that's life :)
http://wp.smashingmagazine.com/2011/10/14/advanced-layout-templates-in-wordpress-content-editor/

Comment: Can you please define the first "section" of your page?  Would it be the first image and paragraph, or maybe just the first paragraph?  We need to know precisely what to target.

Comment: The first section would be the div#featured (I didn't refer to the html section tag). But I'm generally interested in how to insert extra markup in my template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A classic case for Featured images and excerpts!

You would enable both in your functions.php

```
add_post_type_support( 'page', 'excerpt' );
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails');
```

Then in your tempate files (page.php for pages and single.php for posts) you would have

```
 <div id="featured">

      // This is your excerpt

        <?php if(!empty($post->post_excerpt)) { ?>

            <div class="your-excerpt"><?php the_excerpt(); ?></div>

       <?php } ?>

     // And this is your featured image - pulled in at 960 wide

        <?php if (function_exists('has_post_thumbnail') && has_post_thumbnail()) {

            $img_src = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), array( 960,960 )); ?>

            <div class="the-image">
                <img src="<?php echo $img_src[0]; ?>" /> 
            </div>

    <?php }; ?>

  </div>
```

To make sure the excerpts and featured images are visible in the backend, in your page and post edit screen hit the 'Screen options' tab on the top right hand corner and from the drop down make sure that the boxes are checked.  Add your text into the excerpt input box and the upload your image through the featured image dialogue box on the right.

Comment: thanks, I'm gonna give this a try. not yet sure if it is exactly what I need

Comment: Cool - I use it all the time, I always get given designs where the first paragraph is somehow different from the rest of the content.  Excerpts are perfect for that because the clients can use them in Visual view without having to type any html.

Answer (score 0):

You could filter the_content() with the Wordpress API, though, i have no idea if you can accomplish this on your own. Just have a look at this Plugin

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/text-replace/

Which does some Search&Replace in the Content - maybe you can use it. The API for filtering the_content ist described here

http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference